# Consider converge of series[1]

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider converge of series $$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}\right)^{n\ln n}$$

My tried:

Set $u_n= \left(\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}\right)^{n\ln n}$

$\to \sqrt[n]{u_n}= \left(\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}\right)^{\ln n}=\left(1-\frac{2}{2n+1}\right)^{-\frac{2n+1}{2}\times -\frac{2\ln n}{2n+1}}$

Comment: Hint: The sequence behaves *almost* like the harmonic one ($a_n = 1/n$), so the [limit comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) might be a better choice of convergence test.

Comment: Great! Thanks you!